# How to align image vertical?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I need to align image vertically.
So it doesn't matter what's the screen size when entering the page.

Do I need to create .css?

Comment: Yes, you need to use CSS.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vertical-align:top` in css for that.

Comment: Now the image is centered just like using <center> but it's on the top of the page...

Comment: This centers it vertically in its container. Maybe its container is not aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
<img class="yourNeed">

.yourNeed {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```